# Test Web Service is disabled when using Tomcat. What could be the reason for it?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, wsdl, glassfish

I am running Tomcat. When I right-click `Web`, I see that `Test Web Service` is disabled.But when I change the server to `Glassfish`, `Test Web Service` is enabled. What could be the reason for this? I am stuck here for some time and I have not been able to understand the reason.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because NetBeans doesn't include a WebService test client for Tomcat.

From [NetBeans - Getting Started with JAX-WS Web Services - Deploying and Testing the Web Service](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html):

> If you are using the Tomcat Web Server, there is no test client. You
>   can only run the project and see if the Tomcat Web Services page
>   opens.

Maybe you can use the [SoapUI NetBeans IDE Plugin](http://www.soapui.org/IDE-Plugins/netbeans-plugin.html) for testing but it may not work in newer NetBeans releases.